# Is it possible to "tag" people to get their attention?

Tags: support

Sorry, I'm new here. I've noticed that on other social media like Tumblr and Instagram, you can type @(name) to get someone's attention. Is it possible to do that here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this is not a social network, you cannot tag anyone anywhere.

Tagging works in [comments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (50 reputation needed if not on your post), but only if the user you're tagging has already commented on the post (or is the author of the post).

When you reach 20 reputation, you'll get access to the [talk in chat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) privilege. If you know the user you want to ping hangs in a chat, you can @name them there and they'll notice your message when they pass by.

Also, the author of a post is always notified when there is a comment on it, and the author of a question is notified of answers.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @SoItBegins You're welcome, we're all here to ask and answer questions :-)

Comment: If you tag a user in chat, they will get a notification in their bar on any SE site, so it is a pretty good way to get people's attention or send them messages. As long as you don't mind everyone else in chat reading the message. Which you shouldn't, I suppose.